# String array filled with random names

Tags: c++, arrays, string

It's the first time I'm trying something with String Arrays in C++ and yep... I'm stuck.

I'm trying a small programm which will let the user enter max. 10 random Names. If the user enters '.' or has entered 10 nNames the input dialog will end. After he has done this all names will be printed out.

I tried it with a vector, but I guess I be doing something completely wrong...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name;
    int i, counter;
    vector<string> namen_vec;

    cout << endl << "Eingabedialog von maximal 10 Namen. " << endl;
    cout << "Eingabe kann fruehzeitig mit '.' beendet werden. " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    counter = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Eingabe Name: ";
        cin >> name;
        namen_vec.push_back(name);
        counter++;

    } while (name != '.' && counter <= 9);

    for (int i = 0; i < namen_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << namen_vec[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe someone has one or two advices?

Comment: `char name` is a single character, you want a `std::string name`

Comment: *What* is "wrong" with the code you show? What behavior did you expect? What behavior do you get? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please remember how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: you should use std::string type to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have declared the variable `name` as `char` but your container `vector` `namen_vec` accepts a `string`. Still, the program won't be compiled successfully because the following line

```
while (name != '.' && counter <= 9);
```

as `name` would be a string then you have to change this as

```
while (name != "." && counter <= 9);
```

Comment: Please use `code` formatting for code, not bold text. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help